# Does the envoy warforged's Ability Score Increase trait give you a +1 to Con and +1 to two other ability scores? Or just +1 to two ability scores?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, unearthed-arcana, racial-traits, warforged

Does the envoy warforged (from [UA: Eberron Races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf#page=9)) get a +1 to Con *and* +1 to two other ability scores (e.g. Dex and Wis)?

Or only +1 to two ability scores total (e.g. Dex and Wis, or Dex and Con)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. ...Is there a reason you're using the UA version of warforged, instead of the published version, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 5):

### +1 to Con, as well as +1 to any 2 ability scores of your choice

The [version of the warforged from UA: Eberron Races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf#page=8) has the following traits, among others:

> Your warforged character has the following traits.
>
> ***Ability Score Increase.*** Your Constitution score increases by 1.
>
> [...]
>
> ***Subrace.*** As a warforged, your body was designed for a specific
> purpose. Choose one of these subraces: envoy, juggernaut, or skirmisher.

The envoy subrace gains the following additional trait, among others:

> ***Ability Score Increase.*** Two different ability scores of your
> choice each increase by 1.

Per the description of [subraces](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/races#Subraces) in Chapter 2 of the basic rules/PHB:

> Some races have subraces. Members of a subrace have the traits of the
> parent race in addition to the traits specified for their subrace.
> [...]

Therefore, a UA envoy warforged character gains the +1 to Con score from their base race, but also gains the +1 to two different ability scores of the player's choice.

Note that the two different ability scores from the envoy subrace's Ability Score Increase trait only need to be different from one another; nothing prevents you from choosing Con again as one of these two ability scores for the subrace (so you could have +2 to Con and +1 to another ability score if you wanted).

---

Note that the final published version of the [warforged](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged) race, as it appears in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* and the final version of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, has no subraces; its [Ability Score Increase trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged#WarforgedTraits) is worded such that there is no confusion on this subject.

Answer (score 4):

#### Subraces have the traits of the parent race too.

From the [rules for subraces](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/races#Subraces):

> Some races have subraces. Members of a subrace have the traits of the parent race in addition to the traits specified for their subrace.

So you would get the +1 Con from being a warforged (parent race) and the +1 to two other ability scores from being an envoy (sub race).